# NavigationBar titleView jump on viewWillAppear

Tags: swift, ios9, navigationbar, uinavigationitem

I create NavTitleView.xib(added in this xib 2 label "TITLE" and "SUBTITLE") and also create for this xib swift file.

Then i want use this xib as navigationItem.titleView

in viewWillAppear i write this code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)
        let titleView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NavTitleView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! NavTitleView
        titleView.TitleLabel.text = "My beautiful title"
        titleView.SubtitleLabel.text = "My beautiful subtitle"
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

}
```

All works great! But when my view appear - this NavTitleView make jump from left side to center! I don't understand why? How to fix it?

Comment: Move this code to `viewDidLoad` so it's called only once.

Comment: Moving this code to viewDidLoad don't solve problem!! If I move this code in  viewDidLoad- title view will jump once!!!

Comment: @Dmitry you are implementing a custom navigation bar?

Comment: @Dmitry have you found any solution for this please let me know. I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `rightBarButtonItem` set up, try calling `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButton` again inside `viewWillAppear`